# How can I stop my mac from switching desktops when I receive a phone call

Tags: desktop, facetime

When my phone rings the phone call shows up on my mac, which is great except that it also switches my display from the full-screen application to the main desktop screen.

Since the FaceTime popup is basically the same size and shape as a regular notification, is there any way to get it to pop up like other notifications instead of switching to the desktop and interrupting my work?

Comment: the issue still persist on the latest version of Mac which is absurd. I have been facing the same since I activated to receive calls on Mac.  Typical weird stuff from Apple :(

Answer (score 1):

Assign it to either "All Desktops" or "None."  Right Click to access the context menu and then select "Options"

I have mine set to "None" and regardless of where I am, it does't switch but the notification pops up in the Notification center as expected.

[image: FaceTime Desktop Assignment]

Comment: What version of MacOS are you using? This does not appear when I right click FaceTime in the dock and I am using the latest MacOS (Mojave).

Comment: no, this is something different. And the issue still persist on the latest version of Mac. Whenever there's a call notif on Mac, the screen switches if the current screen is in the FULL SCREEN mode irrespective of multiple desktop screens!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Please try closing the FaceTime app. Then see what happens when you receive an incoming call. For me, an incoming call will shuffle me to the desktop where the FaceTime app is displayed, but if it's not open, I just get the notification in the upper right corner with no desktop change.

Comment: What you are describing is how I expect it to work, but that is not what I am experiencing. With the FaceTime app closed, it still switches screens.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the assign desktop options as shown above, you'll have to have multiple desktops open. Three finger gesture swipe up, add a desktop (+ right side of screen), right click FaceTime app to bring up options, you should be able to assign to all desktops now. I assigned to all desktops and it no longer switches when I get a phone call now - just the notification.