# Calls are switched to desktop screen

Tags: macos, bug

I frequently work with tools requiring my full attention on screen and fast reaction times. When I am called on my Mac, however, it switches to my desktop screen and I have to annoyingly click back on the Safari icon to return to my (web-based) application.

I have seen a few questions describing similar issues, often with dual monitors such as here - [How can I stop my mac from switching desktops when I receive a phone call](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/355194/how-can-i-stop-my-mac-from-switching-desktops-when-i-receive-a-phone-call) -  on Stack exchange, but the options described on the post do not exist for me. I have also looked at the options in the apple help forum [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253105959?answerId=255821743022#255821743022) but they have not been of any help.

Aside from trivial bugfixes (deactivating handover, do not disturb), is there any way to deactivate this behavior?

Comment: Have a work account that does not log in to the Apple iD for calls. And then have a personal account you log in to during breaks etc...

Comment: Is there a system-settings-based approach?

Comment: Go to System Preferences and log out of your Apple ID.